# Creating an array of properties of items in an existing array

Tags: arrays, groovy, type-conversion

Probably not the best title, but I'll explain:
I have an array of objects - lets call them `Person`.
Each `Person` has a `Name`. I want to create an array of `Name` respectively.

Currently I have:

```
def peopleNames = new ArrayList<String>()

for (person in people)
{
    peopleNames.add(person.name)
}
```

Does groovy provide a better means of doing so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Groovy provides [a collect method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) on Groovy collections that makes it possible to do this in one line:

```
def peopleNames = people.collect { it.name }
```

Comment: Both methods are good - I chose this as it is a bit more clear and most people maintaining this code are not proficient with `groovy` as it is "only a testing tool"

Answer (score 6):

Or the [spread operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator%28.%29):

```
def peopleNames = people*.name
```

Comment: I always forget about that... Cool!

Answer (score 3):

The most concise way of doing this is to use a GPath expression

```
// Create a class and use it to setup some test data
class Person {

  String name
  Integer age
}

def people = [new Person(name: 'bob'), new Person(name: 'bill')]

// This is where we get the array of names
def peopleNames = people.name

// Check that it worked
assert ['bob', 'bill'] == peopleNames
```

This is one whole character shorter than the [spread operator suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343462/creating-an-array-of-properties-of-items-in-an-existing-array/6343794#6343794). However, IMO both the sperad operator and `collect{}` solutions are more readable, particularly to Java programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this? I like this one because it's so understandable

```
def people = getPeople() //Method where you get all the people
def names = []
people.each{ person ->
   names << person.name
}
```

Comment: I can't see that this is better than using `collect`.  With this method, you need to have a separate line creating the `names` list, and then manipulate the list from inside the loop.  `collect` keeps all this together inside a single block.

Comment: Totally not readable for a `java` developer that never laid eyes on `groovy` code (myself including).
Does this sample use "fixtures"? (I heard the term but don't have any idea what it is)

Comment: @Ron No, it uses the [left shift operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#leftShift%28T%29)

Comment: It's not better, but more understandable than the `collect` operator and more readable for a java developer